# Compare 2 tables in 2 databases

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm trying to compare 2 table that have all the same columns in them in 2 different databases.
The databases are on the same machine, and this is all in SQL database.
I'm trying to retun results from table 2 that do not exist in table 1.
The important column is called Stock.

Lets assume the names as are follows.
DB1 and DB2 as the 2 databases.
The table name for both is Vendor
THe column is Stock

If I use this example I get no results

```
Select * From DB2.Vendor
Where (Stock != Stock)
Except 
Select * From DB1.Vendor
```

Second Idea (this gives me an error)

```
Select * From DB2.Vendor
Union 
Select * From DB1.Vendor
Group by Vendor.Stock
```

If you have a diffrent suggestion great
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Left join or Exists

Left join

```
select a.*
from TestDB2.dbo.Vendor a
left join  TestDB1.dbo.Vendor b on a.Stock=b.Stock 
where b.Stock is  null
```

Exists

```
select *
from TestDB2.dbo.Vendor a
where  not exists (select * from TestDB1.dbo.Vendor b where  a.Stock=b.Stock )
```

Comment: as soon as you said join I realized where this was going.
Thanks

Comment: your welcome ,but exists for your question is better